# How to put random labels in stacked bar plot matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I create a horizontally stacked bar plot as below:-

```
data(1,:)=[0,55,87,96,97,98,99,100,102,125,130];
data(2,:)=[0,55,65,107,110,129,131,0,0,0,0];
data(3,:)=[0,60,104,108,128,130,0,0,0,0,0];
barh(data,'stacked')
axis ij
set(gca, 'xlim',[0,1000], 'box','off');
```

The output is this:
[image]

My question is that i want to put labels inside each box randomly like say this:-

[image]

Labels can be any digit or any letter, not neccesarily 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
y = repelem(1:size(data,1),size(data,2)-1);
x = (cumsum(data(:,2:end),2)-data(:,2:end)./2).';
labels = data(:,2:end).'>0;
text(x(labels),y(labels),num2str((1:nnz(labels)).'))
```

This will print a number increasing by 1 in each box:

[image]

If you want to put random numbers, replace `(1:nnz(labels)).'` with `rand(nnz(labels),1)`. If you want to put characters or mixed content use a cell array with one cell for a label.

Comment: If i want to place the numbers in center of each box, because `11,17` appear very close to boundary, how to control the placement of the text?

Comment: You can use the [`HorizontalAlignment`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html?s_tid=doc_srchtitle#input_argument_namevalue_HorizontalAlignment) property